# How to make a header transparent

Tags: html, css

So I would love to have a transparent header so you don't see a random grey thing hovering in the screen when you scroll I just want the image in the top left to move and is it possible to make the header a little bit smoother because right now it is a little weird

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.ag {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(straat.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.header {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    background: none;
    color: none;
}

.content {
    padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 102px;
}

.logo
{
    Width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Duco's Blog </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<header>

</header>

<body>
    <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <img class="logo" src="leeuw.png">
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onscroll = function() {
            myFunction()
        };

        var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
        var sticky = header.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
                header.classList.add("sticky");
            } else {
                header.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }

    </script>
    <div class="ag"></div>
    <h1>random bs random bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bs</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<header>

</header>

<body>
    <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <img class="logo" src="leeuw.png">
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onscroll = function() {
            myFunction()
        };

        var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
        var sticky = header.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
                header.classList.add("sticky");
            } else {
                header.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }

    </script>
    <div class="ag"></div>
    <h1>random bs random bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bs</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I uderstand, right now the header is transparent. Can you show a picture of the current behaviour and what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add transition for `#header` element via changing of the `opacity` value (just for example).

Or you can change `top` value: when header is visible -> `top: 0`, and when header is hidden -> `top: -100px` (example value, should be equal or more then header height).

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.ag {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(straat.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.header {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    background: none;
    color: none;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.content {
    padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
    /*position: fixed;*/ /* just remove it */ 
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 102px;
}

.logo
{
    Width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Duco's Blog </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<header>

</header>

<body>
    <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <img class="logo" src="leeuw.png">
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onscroll = function() {
            myFunction()
        };

        var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
        var sticky = header.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
                header.classList.add("sticky");
            } else {
                header.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }

    </script>
    <div class="ag"></div>
    <h1>random bs random bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bsrandom bs</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS changes:**
You do not need to include the `<html>` selector, the `<body>` is the part of your HTML document that people see.

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The CSS header is treated like `<body>` (no `.`). I removed `background: none;` because I felt like you really wanted `background-color:transparent;`. I also removed `color: none;` because it refers to the color of your font and it doesn't make sense to not see the words (if there are words). Your HTML tag `<div class="header">` references `#myHeader`, if you need those style declarations add them to your header.

```
header {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    (insert #myHeader styles, if needed)
}
```

I would recommend changing your logo class to `img.logo`, adding the 2 position declarations will create the logo "stickiness" you are looking for. You need both so that people using Safari will have the same experience.

```
img.logo {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    Width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
```

**HTML changes:**
Your `<header>` div needs to be nested inside the `<body>` tag. The `<div class=header">` becomes irrelevant and can be removed. That consoidates your HTML code (from `</head>` to `<script>`) to look like this:

```
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <img class="logo" src="leeuw.png" width="" height="" alt="">
  </header>
  <script>
```

Also of note: The content of  shold be inside your `<div class="ag">`

```
</script>
<div class="ag">
  <h1>random bs ...</h1>
 </div>
```

ok, those are the things I saw that would have prevented you from getting the desired effects. I hope that I explained them in a way that helps you to learn. There are lots of places that offer tutorials.
[W3C.org](https://www.w3.org/) is the authority, use their search form, and 
 [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/default.asp) because they make it all so easy.
Things sure can get sticky: [CSS & HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `background` property with transparent value or you can low the `opacity` but opacity will also decrease the opacity of text color So, I will recommend to use `background` like this :

```
.header {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```